# Geometric problem about triangle [Edited]

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let $|BC|=|AD|=1, \quad\angle BCA=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\angle ACD=\frac{\pi}{6}$. Find $|AB|$.

Can anyone show how to solve it?

Comment: I believe the data is not sufficient. There are many triangles satisfying the same relations, all having different lenghts of the segment $AB$.

Comment: @marcotrevi, Can you give an example of such triangles?

Comment: @RaheemNajib you take any right triangle with one leg $BC$ equal to $1$ and the other leg equal to any quantity you like, they are infinite. You put it down like in the picture above, you prolong the hypothenuse by $1$ to find point $D$. I agree with Marco, there is something missing.

Comment: @GiovanniResta, Thanks! I understand it!

Comment: @marcotrevi, I edited this problem by adding that angle $ACD$ is $\pi/6$

Comment: @GiovanniResta, I edited this problem by adding that angle $ACD$ is $\pi/6$. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Put $|BC|=:a$, $|AB|=:c$, $|AC|=:b$, and denote the angle at $D$ by $\beta$. Two applications of the sine law then give
$${a+c\over\sin 120^\circ}={a\over\sin\beta},\qquad {a\over\sin30^\circ}={b\over\sin\beta}\ .$$
Dividing the first of these by the second we obtain
$${a+c\over a}\cdot{1/2\over\sqrt{3}/2}={a\over b}={a\over\sqrt{c^2-a^2}}\ ,$$
and squaring leads to the equation
$$(a+c)^2(c^2-a^2)=3a^4\ .$$
When $a=1$ we obtain the equation
$$0=(1+c)^2(c^2-1)-3=(c+2)(c^3-2)\ ,$$
which has only one usable solution, namely $c=\root3\of 2$.

Comment: It is remarkable that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ which is known to be not constructible by rule and compass (old problem of the cube duplication) can be "constructed" in this way...

Comment: What about other solution? How you deduced that other solution are not usable?